# Rapidshare API question

Tags: api, rapidshare

When I retrieve response from query http://api.rapidshare.com/cgi-bin/rsapi.cgi?sub=getaccountdetails_v1&type=prem&login=MY_USERNAME&password=MY_PASSWORD, among other variables, I get .............. validuntil=1251783433.........., which should tell me the exact expiration date. My question is how to convert this integer to normal date time format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That number (1251783433) is known as [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).  Most programming languages have methods to convert from Unix time to a date/time format.

Answer (score 1):

The value is probably the Unix timestamp representation of the date.
You can test the value [here](http://www.epochconverter.com/).

```
1251783433
GMT: Tue, 01 Sep 2009 05:37:13 GMT
```

Check the documentation of the programming language you are using to know to create a new Time instance from timestamp.

For instance, in PHP you can format a timestamp with the [date() function](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

```
// prints something like: Tue, 01 Sep 2009 05:37:13 GMT
echo date(DATE_RFC822, 1251783433);
```